# Common Lisp parser that preserves comments

Tags: common-lisp

Common Lisp comes with a parser (reader) that converts its textual syntax to s-expressions. However, it discards comments, making it unsuitable for tools that round-trip Lisp code.

Is there an existing parser for Common Lisp, that preserves comments?

Comment: The reader is customizable. You can make a readtable with your own reader macros on `;` and `#|`.

Comment: What is the ultimate problem you're solving? Correctly round-tripping the syntax of a full language like CL is very complex. You will almost certainly have obscure bugs. I would only try doing this by calling a mature and well-tested open-source library done specifically for the job. If you need only a small subset of CL syntax, it's reasonable to try and write your own parser from scratch.

Comment: Note also that the CL reader relies on a lot of state that is not easy to preserve or replicate. E.g. number radix (10 or 16), symbol case (by default, symbols are converted to uppercase so you would need to preserve the original symbol case, but remember that the user did not use |Pipes-around-the-symbol|), default package in which symbols are interned, etc. And in the general case, any CL code can itself make changes to the readtable :-)

Comment: @Lassi The ultimate problem I'm trying to solve is writing a code formatter. I understand there is no way to preserve all state; at least some things like case folding will be features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're making a code formatter, you might be able to get away with supporting only standard Common Lisp syntax (`with-standard-io-syntax`) and modifying the standard readtable to preserve comments and whitespace (`set-macro-character`). The readtable is the main data structure of the CL reader and tells it which function to call to read different kinds of objects when it encounters a particular character in source code (e.g. how to read a list when it encounters an opening parenthesis).

You have to use either gensyms or structs/classes to represent comments and whitespace, since other kinds of objects (e.g. lists and non-gensym symbols) can be read in from a source file by the Lisp reader using standard IO syntax.

Below is a quick proof of concept. The reader works fine but I couldn't get the printer to work (i.e. re-print the stuff we got from the reader to produce a source file close enough to the input) - it prints extra whitespace around our whitespace, probably because it thinks our whitespace objects are like normal Lisp objects (symbols, lists, etc.) and should be delimited by whitespace when you print several of them in a row (e.g. if you print `1` and `2` and `3` it should print `1 2 3` not `123`). Diving into the guts of the Common Lisp printer to figure out how to override this behavior is left as an exercise for the reader :p

Also, peruse [section 2.4, Standard Macro Characters](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_d.htm) of the Common Lisp HyperSpec. [Section 2.4.8 Sharpsign](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dh.htm) lists all the syntax that starts with `#`. Beware especially of `#+` and `#-` and `#.`

If you ever get this to work well on real code, please consider publishing it as an open-source package.

```lisp
(defstruct comment style string)
(defstruct whitespace string)

(defconstant +whitespace-chars+ '(#\Space #\Tab #\Return #\Newline))
(defconstant +eof+ (gensym "EOF"))

(defun read-semicolon-comment (stream semicolon)
  (declare (ignore semicolon))
  (make-comment :style :semicolon :string
    (with-output-to-string (comment)
      (loop (let ((char (read-char stream nil +eof+ t)))
              (cond ((equal char +eof+) (return))
                ((equal char #\Newline)
                  (unread-char char stream)
                  (return))
                (t (write-char char comment))))))))

(defun read-whitespace (stream first-char)
  (make-whitespace :string
    (with-output-to-string (whitespace)
      (write-char first-char whitespace)
      (loop (let ((char (read-char stream nil +eof+ t)))
              (unless (member char +whitespace-chars+)
                (unless (equal char +eof+) (unread-char char stream))
                (return))
              (write-char char whitespace))))))

(defun read-stream (stream)
  (with-standard-io-syntax ; Here's a comment, for example.
    (let ((*readtable* (copy-readtable)))
      (set-macro-character #\; #'read-semicolon-comment)
      (dolist (char +whitespace-chars+)
        (set-macro-character char #'read-whitespace))
      (loop for x = (read stream nil +eof+) until (equal x +eof+)
        collect x))))

(defmethod print-object ((x comment) stream)
  (assert (equal :semicolon (comment-style x)))
  (write-char #\; stream)
  (write-string (comment-string x) stream)
  x)

(defmethod print-object ((x whitespace) stream)
  (write-string (whitespace-string x) stream)
  x)

(mapc #'prin1 (read-stream *standard-input*))
```

Comment: Thanks! Yep, current work in progress is at https://github.com/russellw/lisp-format

Answer (score 8):

As noted in a comment, you should be able to modify the readtable to bind the macro character `;` to a different reader macro function.  For example, if you define:

```
(defun semicolon-reader (stream char)
  (list 'my-comment
        (concatenate 'string (string char)
                     (read-line stream nil #\Newline t))))
```

and then at toplevel run:

```
> (set-macro-character #\; #'semicolon-reader)
> (read)
```

the user input:

```
(a b ; is b
c ; is c
)
```

will generate:

```
(A B (MY-COMMENT "; is b") C (MY-COMMENT "; is c"))
```

However, real round trip processing is also going to require you to preserve whitespace.  I don't know enough about the reader to know if you could get away with defining some clever macro functions for whitespace characters, or if you'd have to write some kind of preprocessing function to pre-quote runs of whitespace with another macro character and then handle it similarly to `semicolon-reader` above.

Comment: Preserving file offsets could be done with a custom stream class that records the position of elements being read